# arraylist out of range

Tags: java, arrays

i use arraylist to store data , i try the program without any if statement to  read from the file and populate the arraylis and printing it, and it works fine, but when i use iteration and  if statement  and logical conditions it give exception out of range for the arraylist,

```
ArrayList<String> accon = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Double> balance = new ArrayList<Double>();
        try {
            BufferedReader Buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                    "D://transactions.txt")));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = Buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                // String arr[] = line.split(" ");
                String accn = line.substring(0, 17);
                String Case = line.substring(18, 19);

                double a = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(20));
                // System.out.print(balance.size());
                // for (int i = 0; i < accon.size(); i++) {
                int i = 0;
                System.out.print(accon.get(i).equals(accn));
                while (accon.size() >= i) {

                    if (accon.get(i).equals(accn)) {

                        if (Case.equals("D")) {
                            balance.set(i, balance.get(i) - a);

                        } else {
                            balance.set(i, balance.get(i) + a);

                        }
                    } else {
                        accon.add(accn);
                        balance.add(a);

                        // break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }

                // }

            }
            System.out.print("-------------------");
            for (int i = 0; i < accon.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(accon.get(i));
                System.out.println(balance.get(i));
                // System.out.println(accon.size());

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("" + e);
        }
```

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: accon is empty, what other behaviour could you possibly expect?

Comment: Please help us by indicating which line of code that error occurs on

Comment: Please format your code, remove your testing comments lines and specify where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 3):

You dont have any element in the list `accon` but you are using `accon.get(0)` in it

```
 System.out.print(accon.get(i).equals(accn));  //here is the error
```

Causing the error saying you are reading the `0` index but list size is `0`

Answer (score 2):

The `accon`variable has nothing when you try to get things from it, here:

```
System.out.print(accon.get(i).equals(accn));
```

and here:

```
if (accon.get(i).equals(accn)) {
```

Considering your object, the error is in the print command, and your iteration inside the `while` will never be processed because of this: `while (accon.size() >= i) {`.

You must first add the objects to it so you can then iterate and **remove** the objects, so you can get out of the `while`.